# How to use a custom made bower component in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, bower

In my angularjs project I have taken the independent filters and made a bower component so I can use them throughout many projects. I installed that component in my angular project and now what I want to do is add the the bower component as a dependency in my module. I have something like this:

```
 angular.module("app", ["myBowerComponent"])
```

The problem is that the angular module cannot find the dependency meaning the bowerComponent. The name on the folder for the bower component is myBowerComponent so that is what I add as a dependency.

Is there anything else to be done in order the angular.module to find the bower component? I can see the myBowerComponent under bower_component folders, and in bower.json I added the reference manually .

Comment: Are you including the bower component script reference in your html?

Comment: Opss no I have not done that! Let me check it out

Comment: Actually I require the bower scripts in gulp

Answer (score 1):

> The name on the folder for the bower component is myBowerComponent so
>   that is what I add as a dependency.

The "dependency name" needs to be the **angular module name**. For example:

```
// yourBowerComponent.js

var yourModule = angular.module('myBowerComponent', []);

yourModule.factory(/* ... */);
yourModule.directive(/* ... */);

module.exports = yourModule;
```